# Whether the network between Routers are circuit-switched network, and the network connected by Switches are packet-switched network?

Tags: switch, router, network

Whether the network between Routers are circuit-switched network？

and the network connected by Switches are packet-switched network?

[image]

---

**EDIT-01**

I mean if the Net1 can be regarded as `circuit-switched network`, and Net2 can be regarded as packet-switched network?

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking for help with. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @JesseP. I have edited my question.

Comment: Your question is still unclear and cannot be answered by the diagram alone as it doesn't detail what kind of network is used - we could guess but that's off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP networks are packet-switched networks, where a circuit has multiple "conversations" (packets of different flows) running over it.

Circuit-switched networks have a single conversation over a circuit, which is dedicated to the single conversation during the conversation. For example, the traditional PSTN (Public Switched Telephone Network).

Your example has permanent circuits, not switched circuits. The links between the routers do not change, and those links can carry packets from many different flows, so the network is a packet-switched network.